# Move DIV content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I reviewed some of the samples around the block, but nothing is as clear. My problem is as follows: (the subdiv as TEST1, TEST2 are generated dynamically)

FILE1.PHP

```
<div id="MAINLeft">
  <div id="TEST1">
    <form method="post">
      <select name="Select1"
        onchange="AssignOrder(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,TEST1)">
        <option value="A1">Name1</option>
        <option value="B1">Name2</option>
        <option selected="selected">------Select------</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div id="TEST2">
    <form method="post">
      <select name="Select2"
        onchange="AssignOrder(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,TEST1)">
        <option value="A1">Name1</option>
        <option value="B1">Name2</option>
        <option selected="selected">------Select------</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="MAINRight">
</div>
```

So I basically, executing ajax on the background without refreshing the page and displaying the outcome in the MAINRIGHT DIV, and hiding the DIV in the LEFTDIV.

```
function AssignOrder(id,divid)
   {    
     jQuery.ajax({
     type: "GET",             
     url: 'AssignOrder.php',
     data: "id=" + id,
      success: function(data) {
       $('#MAINRight').append(data);
        $(divid).hide();
    }
 });    
 }
```

The function works perfect, but after that I want from the newly displayed DIV in the RIGHTDIV, to click without refreshing the page and return the DIV back into the LEFTDIV, and DELETE, the DIV in the MAINRIGHT DIV.

I used the following, code, but it appears it doesn't work properly.

```
function CancelOrder(id)
   {    
    //to get the ajax content and display in div 
    jQuery.ajax({
    url: $(this).attr('href'),
    success: function(response){
      $(id).show();
    },
    complete: function(){$(this).remove();}
    });
    //stop refreshing to the page given in
    return false;
 }
```

The transferred DIV in the RIGHTDIV has the following line inside:

```
<a href="OrderCancel.php?id=23" onclick="CancelOrder(id)">Cancel</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Generated html doesn't know what id means. OnClick(id), replace it with right id when you are generating these links.

Comment: this looks like a comment.... in case you'd like to answer a question you should provide a complete solution - pls!

Answer (score 0):

If you assign an ID to the link and then pass `this.id` to the `CancelOrder` function it'll work:

```html
<a id="order-cancel-23" href="OrderCancel.php?id=23" onclick="CancelOrder(this.id)">Cancel</a>
```

Comment: Actually the link I have put in my initial page is a raw link. The real think which is in the source of AssignOrder.php
<a href="OrderCancel.php?id=23" onclick="CancelOrderDriver('TEST1')">Cancel</a>. But the click opens a new window and prints the OrderCancel.php file